# SSL handshake exception in WebLogic based middleware

Tags: java, https, ssl-certificate, weblogic-10.x, sslhandshakeexception

I am trying to hit the https api using java code. Which is based on weblogic. When I am hitting the https address then I am getting SSLHandShakeException.
I have placed the jssecerts certificate in the client server taken from the server which i want to access.
Can anyone explain the detailed solution for this.

Comment: You can start by adding debug flags to your server instance to get more info about the issue. Add these flags and set the server log at debug level :  
-Dweblogic.StdoutDebugEnabled=true  
-Dssl.debug=true    
-Djavax.net.debug=all   
-Dweblogic.security.SSL.verbose=true   
-Dweblogic.debug.DebugSecuritySSL=true

Comment: After adding debug flags to startWeblogic.sh. All the debug logs are printed. I am mentioning some of them below. 1) unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object. 2) Ignoring not supported JCE Mac

Comment: The service you are connecting to should use a cryptogrphic algorithm which is not be supported by weblogic server 10. You may have to upgrade to 11g or 12c and use JSEE instead of default ssl implementation provided by WebLogic (Certicom)

Comment: Is there anyway we can solve this and make it work in the WebLogic server 10 itself?